# Overwriting a function defined in a module but before used in its runtime phase?

Tags: perl, compilation

Let's take something very simple,

```
# Foo.pm
package Foo {
  my $baz = bar();
  sub bar { 42 };  ## Overwrite this
  print $baz;      ## Before this is executed
}
```

Is there anyway that I can from `test.pl` run code that changes what `$baz` is set to and causes `Foo.pm` to print something else to the screen?

```
# maybe something here.
use Foo;
# maybe something here
```

Is it possible with the compiler phases to force the above to print `7`?

Comment: It's not an internal function - it's accessible globally as `Foo::bar`, but the `use Foo` will run both the compilation phase (redefining bar if anything was previously defined there) and the runtime phase of Foo. The only thing I can think of would be a deeply hacky `@INC` hook to modify how Foo is loaded.

Comment: You want to redefine the function altogether, yes?  (Not just change part of its operation, like that print?)  Are there specific reasons for redefining before runtime?  The title asks for that but the question body doesn't say/elaborate.  Sure you can do that but I am not sure of the purpose so whether it would fit.

Comment: @zdim yes there are reasons. I want be able to redefine a function used in another module before the runtime phase of that module. Exactly what Grinnz suggested.

Comment: @Grinnz Is that title better?

Comment: Tried another revision to the title...

Comment: A hack is required. `require` (and thus `use`) both compiles and executes the module before returning. Same goes for `eval`. `eval` can't be used to compile code without also executing it.

Answer (score 9):

A hack is required because `require` (and thus `use`) both compiles and executes the module before returning.

Same goes for `eval`. `eval` can't be used to compile code without also executing it.

The least intrusive solution I've found would be to override `DB::postponed`. This is called before evaluating a compiled required file. Unfortunately, it's only called when debugging (`perl -d`).

Another solution would be to read the file, modify it and evaluate the modified file, kinda like the following does:

```
use File::Slurper qw( read_binary );

eval(read_binary("Foo.pm") . <<'__EOS__')  or die $@;
package Foo {
   no warnings qw( redefine );
   sub bar { 7 }
}
__EOS__
```

The above doesn't properly set `%INC`, it messes up the file name used by warnings and such, it doesn't call `DB::postponed`, etc. The following is a more robust solution:

```
use IO::Unread  qw( unread );
use Path::Class qw( dir );

BEGIN {     
   my $preamble = '
      UNITCHECK {
         no warnings qw( redefine );
         *Foo::bar = sub { 7 };
      }
   ';    

   my @libs = @INC;
   unshift @INC, sub {
      my (undef, $fn) = @_;
      return undef if $_[1] ne 'Foo.pm';

      for my $qfn (map dir($_)->file($fn), @libs) {
         open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)
            or do {
               next if $!{ENOENT};
               die $!;
            };

         unread $fh, "$preamble\n#line 1 $qfn\n";
         return $fh;
      }

      return undef;
   };
}

use Foo;
```

I used `UNITCHECK` (which is called after compilation but before execution) because I prepended the override (using `unread`) rather than reading in the whole file in and appending the new definition. If you want to use that approach, you can get a file handle to return using

```
open(my $fh_for_perl, '<', \$modified_code);
return $fh_for_perl;
```

Kudos to @Grinnz for mentioning `@INC` hooks.

Answer (score 8):

Since the only options here are going to be deeply hacky, what we really want here is to run code after the subroutine has been added to the `%Foo::` stash:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# bless a coderef and run it on destruction
package RunOnDestruct {
  sub new { my $class = shift; bless shift, $class }
  sub DESTROY { my $self = shift; $self->() }
}

use Variable::Magic 0.58 qw(wizard cast dispell);
use Scalar::Util 'weaken';
BEGIN {
  my $wiz;
  $wiz = wizard(store => sub {
    return undef unless $_[2] eq 'bar';
    dispell %Foo::, $wiz; # avoid infinite recursion
    # Variable::Magic will destroy returned object *after* the store
    return RunOnDestruct->new(sub { no warnings 'redefine'; *Foo::bar = sub { 7 } }); 
  });
  cast %Foo::, $wiz;
  weaken $wiz; # avoid memory leak from self-reference
}

use lib::relative '.';
use Foo;
```

Answer (score 7):

This will emit some warnings, but prints 7:

```
sub Foo::bar {}
BEGIN {
    $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
        *Foo::bar = sub { 7 };
    };
}
```

First, we define `Foo::bar`. It's value will be redefined by the declaration in Foo.pm, but the "Subroutine Foo::bar redefined" warning will be triggered, which will call the signal handler that redefines the subroutine again to return 7.

Comment: Wellll that's a hack if I've ever seen one.

Comment: This isn't possible without a hack. If the subroutine were called in another subroutine, it would be much easier.

Comment: That will only work if the module being loaded has warnings enabled; Foo.pm doesn't enable warnings and thus this will never be called.

Comment: @szr: So call it with `perl -w`.

Comment: @choroba: Yes, that would work, as -w will enable warnings everywhere, iirc. But my point is that you can't be sure how a user will run that. For example, one-liners typically run sans strictures or warnings.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution that combines hooking the module loading process with the readonly-making capabilities of the Readonly module:

```
$ cat Foo.pm 
package Foo {
  my $baz = bar();
  sub bar { 42 };  ## Overwrite this
  print $baz;      ## Before this is executed
}


$ cat test.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use lib qw(.);

use Path::Tiny;
use Readonly;

BEGIN {
    my @remap = (
        '$Foo::{bar} => \&mybar'
    );

    my $pre = join ' ', map "Readonly::Scalar $_;", @remap;

    my @inc = @INC;

    unshift @INC, sub {
        return undef if $_[1] ne 'Foo.pm';

        my ($pm) = grep { $_->is_file && -r } map { path $_, $_[1] } @inc
           or return undef;

        open my $fh, '<', \($pre. "#line 1 $pm\n". $pm->slurp_raw);
        return $fh;
    };
}


sub mybar { 5 }

use Foo;


$ ./test.pl   
5
```

Comment: @ikegami Thanks, I have made the changes that you recommended. Good catch.

Answer (score 3):

I have revised my solution here, so that it no longer relies on `Readonly.pm`, after learning that I had missed a very simple alternative, based on [m-conrad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58653080/1277321), which I have reworked into the modular approach that I had started here.

**Foo.pm** (*Same as in the opening post*)

```
package Foo {
  my $baz = bar();
  sub bar { 42 };  ## Overwrite this
  print $baz;      ## Before this is executed
}
# Note, even though print normally returns true, a final line of 1; is recommended.
```

**OverrideSubs.pm** *Updated*

```
package OverrideSubs;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Tiny;
use List::Util qw(first);

sub import {
    my (undef, %overrides) = @_;
    my $default_pkg = caller; # Default namespace when unspecified.

    my %remap;

    for my $what (keys %overrides) {
        ( my $with = $overrides{$what} ) =~ s/^([^:]+)$/${default_pkg}::$1/;

        my $what_pkg  = $what =~ /^(.*)\:\:/ ? $1 : $default_pkg;
        my $what_file = ( join '/', split /\:\:/, $what_pkg ). '.pm';

        push @{ $remap{$what_file} }, "*$what = *$with";
    }

    my @inc = grep !ref, @INC; # Filter out any existing hooks; strings only.

    unshift @INC, sub {
        my $remap = $remap{ $_[1] } or return undef;
        my $pre = join ';', @$remap;

        my $pm = first { $_->is_file && -r } map { path $_, $_[1] } @inc
            or return undef;

        # Prepend code to override subroutine(s) and reset line numbering.
        open my $fh, '<', \( $pre. ";\n#line 1 $pm\n". $pm->slurp_raw );
        return $fh;
   };
}

1;
```

**test-run.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use lib qw(.); # Needed for newer Perls that typically exclude . from @INC by default.

use OverrideSubs
    'Foo::bar' => 'mybar';

sub mybar { 5 } # This can appear before or after 'use OverrideSubs', 
                # but must appear before 'use Foo'.

use Foo;
```

***Run and output:***

```
$ ./test-run.pl 
5
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `sub bar` inside `Foo.pm` has a different prototype than an existing `Foo::bar` function, Perl won't overwrite it? That seems to be the case, and makes the solution pretty simple:

```
# test.pl
BEGIN { *Foo::bar = sub () { 7 } }
use Foo;
```

or kind of the same thing

```
# test.pl
package Foo { use constant bar => 7 };
use Foo;
```

---

Update: no, the reason this works is that Perl won't redefine a "constant" subroutine (with prototype `()`), so this is only a viable solution if your mock function is constant.

Comment: `BEGIN { *Foo::bar = sub () { 7 } }` is better written as `sub Foo::bar() { 7 }`

Comment: Re "*Perl won't redefine a "constant" subroutine*", That's not true either. The sub does get redefined to 42 even when it's a constant sub. The reason it works here is because the call gets inlined before the redefinition. If Evan had used the more common `sub bar { 42 } my $baz = bar();` instead of `my $baz = bar(); sub bar { 42 }`, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Even in the very narrow situation it works, this is very noisy when warnings are used. (`Prototype mismatch: sub Foo::bar () vs none at Foo.pm line 5.` and `Constant subroutine bar redefined at Foo.pm line 5.`)

Answer (score 1):

Lets have a Golf contest!

```
sub _override { 7 }
BEGIN {
  my ($pm)= grep -f, map "$_/Foo.pm", @INC or die "Foo.pm not found";
  open my $fh, "<", $pm or die;
  local $/= undef;
  eval "*Foo::bar= *main::_override;\n#line 1 $pm\n".<$fh> or die $@;
  $INC{'Foo.pm'}= $pm;
}
use Foo;
```

This just prefixes the module's code with a replacement of the method, which will be the first line of code that runs after the compilation phase and before the execution phase.

Then, fill in the `%INC` entry so that future loads of `use Foo` don't pull in the original.

Comment: Very nice solution. I had initially tried something like this when I first started, but was missing the injection part + BEGIN aspect that you nicely had connected. I was able to nicely incorporate this into the [modular version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58652059/1277321) of my answer that I had posted previously.

Comment: Your module is the clear winner for design, but I like it when stackoverflow also provides a minimalist answer as well.